# Passing the selected value from select_tag to params without having a form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, submit, parameters

I have this code:

```rb
<div class="export-buttons">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-4">
            <%= label_tag :year, "Any" %>
            <%= select_tag :year,options_for_select((2014..2040).map{|x| x.to_s}),name:"params[year]" %>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
            <%= link_to "Revenue summary", revenue_summary_path(format:"pdf"),class:"btn btn-bg btn-default", role:"button"  %>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
            <%= link_to "Fees summary", fees_summary_path(format:"pdf"),class:"btn btn-bg btn-default", role:"button"  %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I would like to pass the selected value in the `select_tag` to `params`. However I do not have a `form_tag`, hence there's no `Submit` button either.

Is there a way to "embed" it inside the `params` hash? Or do I need a `form_tag` for sure? In case of the latter, what would be the best approach, **two submit-buttons + one path + if/else @controller**?

Comment: Why would you not want a form tag?

Comment: Cause I've got two submit buttons and two different paths. I would like to avoid the if/else at the controller.

Comment: You can specify a path in a button. You need the form to do a submit.

Comment: How can I submit each button to a different path using one single `form_tag`? i.e. different controller. Please note that I'd like to avoid to submit to the same controller action with different parameters and then if/else therein.

Comment: Yes but you pointed that I need a form to do a submit, hence I need to use buttons, not links. Anyway, I'll keep it standard and use a double button inside the form_tab. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to avoid form tags, which may seems logical too since you want to have multiple download links which would simply send out an additional parameter of select_tag to the backend. You can use javascript for same.

- Instead of **link_to** , you can use a binding to a javascript function onclick of these links.
- The binded function would execute the url and before that it would append the current value of select filter via javascript to the url.

Comment: That's a nice suggestion, I'll keep it as an option. However I'd rather have a Javascript-free approach for this.

Comment: You are having fixed 'links' on two buttons. Without modifying the links (via js etc.) or using 'form' , you won't be able to pass additional data to backend..

Comment: That actually answers my original question, ie. whether there is a way to "embed" the info without a form or not. And the answer is **NO** as I'm seeing. I'll keep it standard and use a `form_tag` with double submit buttons. thanks!